Existence of a real continuous function with compact support and Haar integral $1$ over a topological group
I was studying Chapter XII of Lang's book Real and Functional Analysis and came across the following observation (page 315):

Let $h\in C_c(G)$ be a positive function such that
\begin{align*}
\int_Gh\,d\mu=1.
\end{align*}
We can find such $h$ by first selecting a non-empty open set $V$ with compact closure, a function $h_0$ such that $\overline{V}\prec h_0$, and then multiply $h_0$ by a suitable constant.

Here, $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group that is locally compact, $\mu$ is a non-zero Haar measure on $G$, and $C_c(G)$ is the space of continuous functions $G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with compact support. The notation $\prec$ is explained in Chapter IX, §2:

If $K$ is compact we write $K\prec f$ if $f\in C_c(X)$ (here $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space) and $\chi_K\leqslant f\leqslant 1$.

Lemma 2.1 from Chapter IX, §2, states the following: Given $K$ compact, $K\subset V$ open, there exists some $f$ such that $K\prec f\prec V$. Using this result, I can conclude that there exists a function $h_0\in C_c(G)$ such that $\overline{V}\prec h_0$. Then $I_0=\int_Gh_0\,d\mu\leqslant\sup(h_0)\mu(\text{supp}(h_0))<\infty$ (since $h_0$ is bounded by $1$ and the Haar measure is finite on compact sets). Now, if $I_0>0$, then the function $h=h_0/I_0$ satisfies the desired conditions. So my question is:

How do we know that we can choose $h_0\in C_c(G)$ with $\overline{V}\prec h_0$ (for this particular choice of $V$) in such a way that $I_0\neq0$?

I can see from the inner and outer regularity of $\mu$ that there always exists an open set $U$ and a compact set $K$ with $\mu(U),\mu(K)>0$. But how do we know that the compact set $\overline{V}$ doesn't have measure zero?

Since $\mu$ is invariant, every nonempty open subset has positive measure.

@MoisheKohan I've recently started studying topological groups, and I don't have much experience with measures. I know that the Haar measure is left-invariant, but I don't see how that implies that every non-empty open set has positive measure. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Finitely many translates of $V$ cover $K$. If $V$ has measure zero, then all the translates do as well, implying that $K$ has measure zero.

@MatheusFrota Note that Lang in his book defines a Haar measure to be positive on all non-empty open sets. So since we assume here this is a Haar measure, in particular $\mu(V)>0$.
